# Display Multi Word Categories As 1 Word With Dashes

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have some child pages that have categories associated with them. For categories that have more than 1 word e.g "Test Category" I need the output to be 1 word with the spaces separated by dashes e.g "Test-Category"

How can the function be rewritten to handle this?

```
public function CategoriesList() {
    if ($this->Categories()->exists()) {
        return implode(', ', $this->Categories()->column('Title'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create a `getDashedTitle` function in our `Category` class to return a title with dashes instead of spaces:

```
class Category extends DataObject {
    public function getDashedTitle() {
        return str_replace(' ', '-', $this->Title);
    }
}
```

We can then use `DashedTitle` in the `map` function to fetch the category dashed titles:

```
public function CategoriesList() {
    if ($this->Categories()->exists()) {
        return implode(', ', $this->Categories()->map('ID', 'DashedTitle')->toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I went with as it's a pretty simple use case in my situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [Extension](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/) for this. This means that this method will be available for any varchar field.

**mysite/code/extensions/VarcharDecorator.php**

```
<?php
class VarcharDecorator extends Extension {
    function Slugify() {
        return FileNameFilter::create()->filter(trim($this->owner->value);
    }
}
```

**mysite/_config/extensions.yml**

```
Varchar:
  extensions:
    - VarcharDecorator
```

Now you can use **$Title.Slugify** in your templates.

```
<% loop $Categories %>
  $Title.Slugify<% if not $Last %>, <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but assuming `Categories()` returns a `HasManyList` you could try something like this:

```
public function CategoriesList()
{
    if (!$this->Categories()->exists()) {
        return '';
    }

    $output = [];
    foreach ($this->Categories() as $category) {
         $output[] = implode('-', explode(' ', $category->Title()));
    }

    return implode(', ', $output);
}
```

This will break the title up by spaces then put it back together with dashes, finally joining all Titles together with `,` and returning that.

Answer (score 2):

The `FileNameFilter` class will do what you need out of the box:

```
FileNameFilter::create()->filter("Test Category 1")
```

For more flexibility or custom functionality, you could extend the class and overload the filter function:

```
class CategoriesFilter extends FileNameFilter {

  public function filter($name) {
    //do your processing on $name
    return $name;
  }

}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I wasn't aware of this function.